# Typescript: Declare functions without implementing them

Tags: class, typescript, sapui5

Is it possible to declare that a class has certain functions without implementing them?

I need this because I create a class that is then passed to a js framework which adds a couple of functions. I wanna be able to call those functions aswell without reimplementing them, redirecting or casting or whatsoever.

Example:

```
//example class
class AppComponent {
   constructor() {}
}

//create class
var comp: AppComponent = new AppComponent();

//hand over to framework
fw.define("Component", comp);

//now I want to be able to call the added functions such as:
comp.setModel(/*some model*/);
```

Comment: I guess you can have an `interface` with these methods and the call to `fw.define` could be typed to return an object of that interface (just gives you `comp` back again, but you can assign it to a typed second variable). Or just cast your `comp` to that interface (possibly via `any`).

Comment: unfortunately `define` doesn't return anything. thats why i cast it to `sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller`(framework SAPUI5) defined in a d.ts file. Easiest would be a way to combine both

Comment: `declare that a class has certain functions without implementing them`: that is what [abstract classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) are made for

Comment: @BrunoGrieder the problem with them is that they can not be instantiated,  the framework would have to create a subclass of it. It would probably be better to just define an interface with some optional properties that the framework can set.

Comment: but using an abstract class i have to implement the functions somewhere later in a derived class. I don't want to implement those functions at all because they are already implemented in a javascript framework

Comment: I need sth like `class AppComponent contains sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller {}` which basically tells typescript that its ok to call sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller functions on AppComponent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may declare the function without implementing it.

```
//example class
class AppComponent {
    constructor() { }
    setModel: () => void;
}

//create class
var comp: AppComponent = new AppComponent();

//hand over to framework
fw.define("Component", comp);

//now I want to be able to call the added functions such as:
comp.setModel(/*some model*/);
```

Comment: thats what i need, thanks. But is there a way without arrow functions?

Comment: Its the way TypeScript declares functions.

Comment: but it declares it as an arrow function, so if i want to overwrite it in a derived class I also have to use arrow functions. (which causes problems with the framework because it calls functions with another `this` than the class instance `this`. In arrow functions `this` is bound to class instance)

Comment: The declaration uses the arrow, but you don't have to use it when assigning. `comp.setModel = function() {};`

Comment: How do we declare function when it has a return type? @Rodris

Comment: @Kitwradr Change the `void` to your return type.