# Javascript function without curly braces

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, angular-material, node-modules

A **good function** is declared as follows:

```
export declare class SOMETHING implements OnDestroy {

    sayHello() {
       // some code to say hello
    }

}
```

But in `node_modules` (angular material specifically) I found this function code in `typesript`:

```
export declare class SOMETHING implements OnDestroy {

    sayHello(parA: string, parB?: string: parC: MatSnackBarConfig): MartSnackBarRef<SimpleSnackBar>;

}
```

But.... where is the `{}` in the function sayHello?

Where I can find information about this topic?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript: Declare functions without implementing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653623/typescript-declare-functions-without-implementing-them)

Answer (score 2):

It's called a method declaration. You are stating to typescript that this method will be implemented and that it will be it's type.

It's useful in Interfaces and Abstract classes, and also method overload.

For example, the overload, in here I declare that the method `findOneAndUpdate` have two different way to be called, which leads to two different results.

```
  public findOneAndUpdate<U = T>(data: {
    where?: unknown | {};
    action?: unknown | {};
    option?: MongooseOptionsReq;
    session?: false | mongoose.ClientSession;
    createObject: true;
    mustExist?: boolean;
    noLean?: boolean;
    schemaPosition?: number;
  }): Promise<CollectionDocument<U>>;

  public findOneAndUpdate<U = T>(data: {
    where?: unknown | {};
    action?: unknown | {};
    option?: MongooseOptionsReq;
    session?: false | mongoose.ClientSession;
    createObject?: false;
    mustExist?: boolean;
    noLean?: boolean;
    schemaPosition?: number;
  }): Promise<U>;
```

In addition to the type declaration, of course you need to implement the method :

```
public findOneAndUpdate<U = T>({
    where = {},
    action = {},

    option = {
      new: true,
    },

    createObject = false,
    session = false,
    mustExist = false,
    noLean = false,
    schemaPosition,
  }: {
    where?: unknown | {};
    action?: unknown | {};
    option?: MongooseOptionsReq;
    session?: false | mongoose.ClientSession;
    createObject?: boolean;
    mustExist?: boolean;
    noLean?: boolean;
    schemaPosition?: number;
  }): Promise<CollectionDocument<U>> | Promise<U> {
      // ...
  }
```

Comment: To add to this, this is a way that type definitions are frequently exposed is through declaration files `.d.ts`, sometimes in cases where the underlying code isn't actually TypeScript but you want TS-compatible hints.

Answer (score 0):

This is closely related to abstract method deceleration - but more flexible without the `abstract` keyword. This way it is possible to expose the shape of the parent class in a more type conscious way.

```
class Parent {

   hello(x: number): number;
}


class Child extends Parent {

   hello() {
      console.log('hello');
   }
}


c = new Child();

c.hello()
```

Read here for more information:

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#abstract-classes